# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: Dynamic Web Project Tomcat Run Time Exception

Tags: java, google-chrome

I hava a bunch of excel sheets which I want to zip and enable the user to download it. For Zipping all excel sheets, I have used java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream library.

**Code Snippet is given below** :

```
protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object command,
            BindException errors) throws Exception {
    // some code to get the list
    Iterator<StudentSheet> it = list.iterator();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
    while (it.hasNext()) {
         StudentSheet is = it.next();
         String fileName = is.getStudentCode() + "_" + is.getStudentName() + ".xls";
         fileName = fileName.replaceAll(" ", "_");
         logger.debug("FileName: " + fileName);
         ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
         byte[] input =StudentManager.loadStudentSheetExcel(is.getId());
         entry.setSize(input.length);
         zos.putNextEntry(entry);
         zos.write(input);
         zos.closeEntry();
      }
    zos.close();
    String zipFileName = "ABC.zip";
    logger.debug("ZipFileName: " + zipFileName);
    try {
       streamZipOutput(zipFileName, "application/zip", baos, response);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally {
        baos.close();
    }
    return null;
}



public void streamZipOutput(String zipFileName, String type, ByteArrayOutputStream baos,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + zipFileName + "\"");
        response.setContentType(type);

        response.getOutputStream().write(baos.toByteArray());
        response.flushBuffer();

    }
```

This code is running **absolutely fine from Google Chrome browser** . When I run my application from internet explorer, i GET this exception during runtime :

```
Feb 11, 2017 5:45:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [action] in context with path [/appName] threw exception
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: 110_Vedant.xls
    at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.putNextEntry(ZipOutputStream.java:232
```

I am not able to figure out why duplicate entry issue. **The names of each excel file is unique and chrome doesn't give any such exception if I generate this same thing.** Help me figure out how I can resolve this. What is causing this problem .

**My internet explorer version : 11.713.10586.0**

**EDIT**
Earlier my submit button was like this :

```
<div id="pageButtons">
  <button type="submit" onClick="sendAction('submit')"> Submit </button>
</div>
```

And the sendAction function was like :

```
function sendAction(anAction){
   document.form._action.value = anAction ;
   document.form.submit();
}
```

So since the button type is submit and also in the function sendAction I am doing submit by code, so I think it was getting submitted twice concurrently.

So I changed the button HTML part to :

```
<div id="pageButtons">
      <button onClick="sendAction('submit')"> Submit </button>
</div>
```

Still It was getting submitted twice.

Then I changed it to :

```
<div id="pageButtons">
      <button type="button" onClick="sendAction('submit')"> Submit </button>
</div>
```

Then It worked fine in IE.
Now what I am not able to understand is, if the type="submit" thing was resulting into form submission twice in IE, why was it working fine in Chrome.
In chrome also, it should submit twice because button type is submit and I have also hardcode "**document.form.submit()**".

Can anyone give me the reason ?

Comment: I assume that it is thrown here: zos.putNextEntry(entry); It is deep inside the server. No bowser specific code. Could you check that same request is not sent twice concurrently?

Comment: @efekctive Yes when I run from IE , the request is going twice concurrently. In chrome, it is just going once. Why is it so ? Can u help ?

Comment: The only thing that occurs to me is to identify your requests/session and keep track of them on the server.

Comment: Hi @efekctive I have update my Question. Please see the Edit part. My issue is resolved but I have a follow up question if u can help. Thanks

Comment: Another way of doing it. Post the question. Somebody will pick it up

Answer (score 0):

My submit button type was type="submit" and I was also making a call to a javascript function onClick of this submit button. In that Javascript function, I had written document.form.submit() , So the form was getting submitted twice concurrently.

```
<div id="pageButtons">
  <button type="submit" onClick="sendAction('submit')"> Submit </button>
</div>
```

And the sendAction function was like :

```
function sendAction(anAction){
   document.form._action.value = anAction ;
   document.form.submit();
}
```

So I changed my submit button type as :

```
<div id="pageButtons">
      <button type="button" onClick="sendAction('submit')"> Submit </button>
</div>
```